# how to append li tag into ul in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a html like this

```
  <div>
       <div class="submain">
           <div><ul><ul><div>
           <div g-directive>click</div>
       </div>
       <div class="submain">
           <div><ul><ul><div>
           <div g-directive>click</div>
       </div>
       <div class="submain">
           <div><ul><ul><div>
           <div ng-directive>click</div>
       </div>
  <div>
```

when i click on particular div(click div), i want to append one li tag into  the ul tag of before particular clicked div.

i have directive like this,  i have tried this but it is not working

```
app.directive('ngDirective',function()
{
   return function(scope,element,attrs)
   {
      element.bind('click',function()
      {
          element.prev().children('ul').append('<li></li>');

      });
   }

});
```

how to append li tag into ul that is children of div ?

Comment: What's in the `<li>` tag.  With angular, you should work with the data and then use something like `ng-repeat` to build the DOM.

Comment: yes...i have used ng-repeat but it is binding data into all li tag of ul tag...but i want to bind data into only specific li tag ...

Comment: Then write in that li, bind the data to it, and then use something like ng-show to control when it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Just a rough example of what you could do:

HTML

```
<div>
   <div class="submain">
       <div><ul>
         <li ng-show="showLI">{{content}}</li>
       <ul><div>
       <div ng-click="toggleLI()">click</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

JS

```
$scope.showLI = false;
$scope.toggleLI = function() {
    $scope.showLI = !$scope.showLI;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work, because of wrong element selector. `.children` searches only the first level of children elements, so basically `<div class="submain">` doesn't have children element `<ul>`. You can use `.find('ul')` instead, it searches the whole tree downwards